# Display mean and std dev from 2 columns in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dat file like

```
2013-08-25,6.123,1.01
2013-08-25,7.163,1.28
...
```

Where the first column is date, second is mean, third is std dev

Is there a way I can make a plot that has the mean as a line and then a box/cloud/whatever representing the mean +/- 1 std dev?

Comment: it is confused, can you explain again please

Comment: Something like... plot "file.dat" using 1:2 index 0 title "Mean" with lines, "file.dat" using 1:2:3 title "StdDev" with errorbars but with more continuous "bars"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filledcurves` plot style to mark the region of +- the standard deviation:

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc rgb '#ffcccc' title 'StdDev',\
     '' using 1:2 with lines lc rgb 'red' title 'Mean'
```